# Equivalent of MSVC++ _wrename in linux g++?

Tags: linux, visual-c++, unicode, g++, rename

Does anyone know if an equivalent of MSVC **_wrename** exist in linux g++ ? (equivalent of cstdio file **rename** function using **const wchar_t*** instead of **const char*** as parameter type for unicode use)

Thanks !

Comment: My copy of the mingw-w64 CRT has this. Or are you looking for a Linux/POSIX alternative?

Comment: I'm looking for a linux alternative, I should have precised. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 3):

The point is that most filesystems *other* than NTFS store their filenames in *byte*-strings. There is usually no explicit notion of encoding, but the filenames have to be strings of non-zero bytes terminated by a zero. So on all such systems, filesystem functions just take `char*` arguments for filenames, and you have to figure our yourself how to handle encoding issues (should there be any).

Windows is special because filenames in NTFS are null-terminated strings of 16-bit units. This goes hand-in-hand with the 16-bit `wchar_t` type on Windows and various `_w*` filesystem functions.

Comment: Very interesting thanks. There is still something I don't get. On linux, when using stdio rename, how the system knows that we pass an ascii 8bit-string or an encoded unicode 16bit-string (passed as simple 8bit-string) ? (i don't know if my question is clear...)

Comment: @Juicebox: The filesystems that I know of don't have a notion of encoding. You just pass them whatever you think is the right filename. By the way, there is no such thing as "8 bit ASCII" or a "unicode 16-bit string". You probably mean something else.

Comment: As a corollary, most filesystems don't have a notion of "characters" comprising a filename, only "code units". You cannot in full generality ask for "how many characters does this filename have" (e.g. a filename might consist of a single rogue Unicode surrogate). This is just the fundamental difference between a string of bytes and a notion of "text comprised of characters". The former is very easy, the latter fiendishly hard.

Comment: The 8bit-string and 16bit-string are just there to explain my question of : how is interpreted the passed bytearray inside the rename func... If it's as a pure ascii byte string or anything else. Globally i know that "characters" don't exist as it, only bytes that are interpreted differently depending on the encoding. The main problem I have is that I try to make generic the use of string (char or wchar_t strings) in my API and i'm stucked because i don't know how to handle unicode filename (rename,...) in my GNU/g++ specific code for linux (like chinese filename for example).

Comment: @Juicebox: It is not interpreted at all. There is simply nothing related to encodings on the Linux filesystem level: no ASCII, no Unicode, no whatever. You pass the function a sequence of bytes, and the system just uses exactly that sequence of bytes. If you have a Unicode string, you usually take the information which encoding the system might expect from the locale environment variables.

Comment: @Philipp : ok I see, tell me if i'm wrong... so in fact the sequences of bytes passed to rename(const char*,const char*) are not really "name" as I thought, it's the bytedata that represents the name in the filesystem, right ? I mean, there is no intermediate treatment of that sequence of bytes before being saved to the filesystem ?

Comment: @Juicebox: The filename **is** the sequence of bytes. It's up to you to interpret those in a textual way. For ASCII this is usually consensual, but for anything that goes beyond that you have to have to have some additional knowledge of how to interpret the byte sequence. But think it through, you'll see that there isn't really a need for the filesystem to know about text. It's up to the program to communicate with the user and decide which files to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

That's platform specific. I'm afraid you'll have to convert your const wchar_t* to const char* somehow. On Linux, i think you can use the iconv function.

**EDIT**: Boost probably has something for this

Comment: Indeed, i didn't think about Boost but it seems that it has something like that in the filesystem lib. I check it and say if it fits what I need. Thanks.

Comment: The C++ standard (until 0x) doesn't deal with Unicode at all. Both `char` and `wchar_t` are almost totally unspecified and have nothing to do with Unicode (or "characters", for that matter).

Comment: @Philipp: And what about wstring?

Comment: @dario: `wstring` is just a sequence of `wchar_t`s, so the same points apply. Quoting the Unicode standard, "The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text."

Comment: Like Dave Mustaine said, "I thought I knew it all..." :P. Thanks, didn't know that. Corrected my answer

Comment: Regarding Boost: It has a portable [filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) (make sure you use version 3), which incorporates a [`rename` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#rename). For a portable C++ application, that would probably be my first choice.