# Opening Unicode filenames in windows from DOS 8.3 filenames

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, fstream

Can I generate a 8.3 filename for a unicode filename and use that ASCII string of char's to open an `fstream` in Windows?

I know that MSVC++ provides a `wchar_t*` overload for `fstream`, but GCC's libstdc++ does not provide this :(, so I need an alternative. I don't want to create my own streambuf class just for this, as it seems overkill.

Comment: It doesn't overload, it has the std::wfstream class.  Which is part of the standard C++ library.  Surely you can find a crt that implements it.

Comment: @Hans: The wfstream is a stream whose *data* comes in units of `wchar_t`, but are you sure that it is able to open files by `wchar_t*`?

Comment: @Hans: I want an `fstream` because the file is UTF-8, I don't want to extract `wchar_t`s from it. But The filename can contain non-ASCII characters of course.

Comment: @Hans: and a `std::wfstream` opens a `char*` filename, not `wchar_t*`...

Comment: 8.3 filenames are only for legacy applications and can be disabled. Don't ever use them. If you must use GCC, you probably have no other choice than to skip the whole standard library and use the Windows API directly (`CreateFileW` etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably leverage the Windows API function [`GetShortPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to give you the short name. You cannot "compute" the name algorithmically as there is no one-to-one correspondence between an arbitrary long name and a short name, and I don't think you can avoid using the Windows API for the translation.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but would this work for opening `fstream`s for unicode filenames?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "unicode filename" (e.g. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442045/equivalent-of-msvc-wrename-in-linux-g/6442665#6442665)). But you can only pass a `char*` to `fstream`, so on Windows you better use the short filename, which you obtain from your "unicode name" by said API function.

Comment: GetShortPathName is designed to be backwards compatible with older filesystems, so it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, OK, that was exactly the plan. I know my wording isn't exact, but on Windows, it's accurate enough to get my question across. Thanks! Your link exemplifies my issue.

Comment: This won't work, because the result of `GetShortPathNameW` would also be a wide string, unusable for C++'s `ifstream`. Web sources seem to suggest I'd need to convert the string to the 8-bit local codepage, will that work?

Comment: @Rubenvb: You can safely convert the result of the W version to a char-string with `wcstombs`, the short path name is guaranteed to be ASCII only, so you don't even need to bother with the locale.